# jQuery: Apply CSS to parent DIV

Tags: jquery, css, parent

Let's say I'm doing a code. This code uses kontextua ads

```
<div class="pread">
    <div class="postad kontextuaDisplayREGULARS728x90">
    <div style="display: block !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important; margin-right: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important; overflow-x: hidden !important; overflow-y: hidden !important; padding-bottom: 2px !important; padding-left: 4px !important; padding-right: 4px !important; padding-top: 2px !important; z-index: 10000 !important; ">
        <iframe style="display: block; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: transparent; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " frameborder="0" width="728px" height="90px" src="javascript:(function(){return '<html><meta http-equiv=\'Content-Type\' content=\'text/html\' charset=\'UTF-8\'></meta><head><style> html { overflow:hidden; } body { background-color:transparent; float:left; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden; height:90px;width:728px;} .contenido{margin:0}</style></head><body><div class=\'contenido\' id=\'banner\'><SCRIPT TYPE=\'text/javascript\' SRC=\'http://ad.yieldmanager.com/st?ad_type=ad&ad_size=728x90&section=2871061\'></SCRIPT></div></body></html>'})()"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wan't to know when clicked and apply a CSS to parent ".pread". How can I do this?

```
<script>
        $(".postad").live('click', function(){
        alert("clicked");
            $(this).parent().css({
                'backgroundImage' : 'url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/DarkGlass_Reworked/128x128/actions/camera_test.png)',
                'backgroundColor' : 'limeGreen'
            });
        });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: its working fine in your fiddle. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works if you give some actual content to the postad div other than the iframe.  You can [see it work here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TtqpJ/) if you click on the xxx that I added to that div.

It does not work if you click on the `iframe` and that's because clicks don't bubble out of an `iframe` into parent objects so when you click in the iframe, no click event is received in the `postad` div.  If you click on the iframe, the click stops there.

It is possible to intercept a click on an iframe from the parent page, but that involves putting a transparent div over the top of the iframe so the parent page gets the click, not the iframe.  You can see the transparent div idea work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h2WTB/ - just click on the download image and the click will be handled by the transparent div which will bubble to your `postad` event handler.

Comment: So how can I check if it is clicked?

Comment: @Luis - see my second example that actually executes your code (lime green background-color and the alert).

Comment: This is what I need, now any kind of ForceClick to iframe? So it doesn't stop the main click function?

Comment: @Luis - Since you're generating the content of the iframe yourself and therefore it's sourced to the same domain as the parent window, why don't you just put the click handler on the iframe or an object in the iframe and handle it directly in there?  Or stop using an iframe since you aren't loading remote content into it.

Answer (score 1):

You got your CSS properties wrong.  They're hyphenated, not camelCase.

```
$(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/DarkGlass_Reworked/128x128/actions/camera_test.png")',
    'background-color' : 'limeGreen'
});
```

Comment: Do you mean you're getting an error message in your browser, or the image/color aren't applied?

Comment: The image/color aren't applied.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".postad").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
            $(this).parents('.pread').css({
                'backgroundImage' : 'url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/DarkGlass_Reworked/128x128/actions/camera_test.png)',
                'backgroundColor' : 'limeGreen'
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

It's should work good :)

Comment: Did you actually try this?  It doesn't look to me like it would generate any different result than what the OP already has.